# equation involving absolute value function has $4$ solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If the equation $|x^2-5|x|+k|-\lambda x+7 \lambda = 0$ has exactly $4$ solution, Then $(\lambda,k)$ is

Attempt:$x^2-5|x|+k = \lambda x-7 \lambda$

$\star$ For $x>0,$ then $x^2-5x+k=\lambda x- 7 \lambda.$

$\star$ For $x\leq 0,$ then $x^2+5x+k=\lambda x- 7 \lambda.$

could some help me how to go further,thanks

Comment: 1) Your conclusions are false: for example $x>0 \implies x^2-5x+k=\color{red}{\pm}(\lambda x- 7 \lambda)$. 2) I imagine  this is homework. Are some solutions proposed (it must be some domains for $\lambda$ and $k$) ?

Comment: It is not an hard problem, but too many cases and no nice numbers, so I gave up. As an hint, separate the absolute value on the LHS and put the remaining on the RHS. Now you can visualise the LHS as $k$ varies and find the tangent points with the line bundle in the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arranged a graph for you: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fdrcwuc5gg

Try to use the slider you will find the following cases:

$k<0$) 2 sets of solutions: ${k \over 7}<\lambda <0$ and $-19+2\sqrt{k+84}<\lambda <-9+2\sqrt{k+14}$

$0<k<231-14\sqrt{266}$) 4 intersections for: $-19+2\sqrt{k+84}<\lambda <-9+2\sqrt{k+14}$

$231-14\sqrt{266}<k<161-42\sqrt{14}$) 4 intersections for: $-9+2\sqrt{k+14}<\lambda <-{k\over 7}$

$161-42\sqrt{14}<k<{25\over 4}$) 4 intersections for: $-{k\over 7} <\lambda<-9+2\sqrt{k+14} $

$k>{25\over 4}$) 4 intersections for: $9-2\sqrt{k+14}  <\lambda<-{k\over 7}  $

${25\over 4}$ is the vertex of the parabolas, you'll find the other two numbers equating the lambdas at the extreme points when the line passing through the cusp at $0$ is also tangent to a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that if $\lambda=k=0$ then the only solutions are $0,\,-5$ and $5$.

Suppose $\lambda=0$ and $0<k<\dfrac{25}{4}$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
 {\Big\vert}\, |x|^2-5|x|+k\, {\Big\vert}&=&0\\
{\Huge\vert}\left(|x|-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+k-\frac{25}{4}{\Huge\vert}&=&0\\
\left(|x|-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2&=&\frac{25}{4}-k\\
|x|&=&\frac{5}{2}\pm\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{4k}{25}}>0
\end{eqnarray}

Thus there are only four solutions

$$ x=\pm\frac{5}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{4k}{25}}\,\right) $$

provided that $(\lambda,k)=(0,k)$ and $0<k<\dfrac{25}{4}$.

This does not exhaust the solutions. [Graphing techniques](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/en0mksfrp1) indicate that if $k=0$ then there is an open interval containing $\lambda=-1$ for which there are only four **real** solutions. But perhaps we are including complex solutions?

Was the object to **characterize** all possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

No harm in doing it in a case by case basis.

You have

$x^2\pm 5x +k = \pm(\lambda x-7 \lambda)$

That's four equations to solve:

1) $x^2+  5x +k = \lambda x-7 \lambda\implies x^2 + x(5 - \lambda) + (k+7\lambda) = 0$

2) $x^2- 5x +k = \lambda x-7 \lambda \implies x^2 + x(-5 - \lambda) + (k+7\lambda) = 0$

3) $x^2+  5x +k = -\lambda x+7 \lambda\implies x^2 + x(5 + \lambda) + (k-7\lambda) = 0$

4) $x^2-  5x +k = -\lambda x+7 \lambda\implies x^2 + x(-5 + \lambda) + (k-7\lambda) = 0$